# Simple spring integraction xml config to read ftp file list and split it further

Tags: spring-integration

I am studying spring integration and want to write simple app to retrieve the filelist from the ftp by scheduler and split it to few channels to parallel handling.

But couldn't understand how to run it from xml configured scheduler and will it work as it outbound and what should be in inbound1 channel? (code section)

searched such examles, but failed, reading ref docs

found from doc reference

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gateway1"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inbound1"
    command="ls"
    command-options="-1"
    expression="payload"
    reply-channel="toSplitter"/>

<int:channel id="inbound1"/>

   <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="i_hope_it_start_run_on_app_start"
                                             channel="inbound1"
                                             auto-startup="true">
       <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" max-messages-per-poll="10"/>
   </int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

expect spring integration xml config with scheduled run retrieving file list from ftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you go right way: the `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` with `LS` command indeed returns for you a list of files in the remote directory provided by the `expression="payload"`.

Your understanding about `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` is also correct: with it your really initiate a task to be called every time trigger comes to activity.

What you need here is something like `expression="'/YOUR_REMOTE_DIR'"`. So, the result of that expression is sent as a payload to the `channel="inbound1"`. That's how your remote directory can be available for listing in the FTP gateway via mentioned `expression="payload"`.

I wouldn't do though a `fixed-rate="2000"` because there is no reason to poll remote directory concurrently. The `fixed-delay` should be considered instead. Also the `max-messages-per-poll="10"` doesn't bring value here, too. You just going to send a message with the `/YOUR_REMOTE_DIR` 10 times on a single polling task. Configure it to `1`, which is default in case of `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

Plus with such a polling logic you will realize that you get in the `toSplitter` the same list of files all the time. I may guess that it is not what you may expect and your goal is really poll only new files. For this purpose you should consider to use an `Idempotent Receiver` approach to filter out those files you have already processed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver